# Adding Objects to a List, cant assign to Add because it is a group method

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently getting an error with the below code, and I don't know how to fix it!

This is the error:
`Cannot assign to 'Add' because it is a 'method group'`

Here is my App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    //Public list of users and form can access
    List<User> LoggedUsers = new List<User>();

    //First startup of the application
    public void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //First startup, display the login form
        LoginWindow FirstLogin = new LoginWindow();
        FirstLogin.ShowDialog();

        //If the login form was closed properly, handle the user
        if (FirstLogin.DialogResult == true)
        {
            //Add the user to the list of logged users
            User returned = FirstLogin.returnUser;

            //Create temp duplicate for testing
            User tmp = new User();
            tmp.Email = "email@gmail.com";
            tmp.FirstName = "John";
            tmp.LastName = "Johnson";
            tmp.ID = "01";
            tmp.Permissions = 1;

            LoggedUsers.Add = tmp;
            LoggedUsers.Add = returned;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my LoginWindow.xaml.cs which the User Object is returned from when closed (returned):

```
//Give App access to user object outside of this form
public User returnUser
{
    get
    {
        return user;
    }
}

//Public user object, start empty
User user = new User();

//Check the login
private void doLogin(string username, string password)
{
    //User logged in, add data to user object
    user.Email = "email@gmail.com";
    user.FirstName = "John";
    user.LastName = "Johnson";
    user.ID = "01";
    user.Permissions = 1;

    //Close the form with dialog result "true"
    this.DialogResult = true;
    this.Close();
}
```

And the class, incase you need that:

```
//Logged in users class
Public Class User
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Int16 Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Adding a duplicate object to the List for some testing purposes when I have fixed this.

Comment: Woops sorry, forgot as it was making me wait afew minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`List.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method not a property:

```
LoggedUsers.Add(tmp);
LoggedUsers.Add(returned);
```

Comment: Crap, something that simple :( Thanks!